# pyspark withcolumn condition based on another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have input:

dataframe A:

```
valueX valueY
     1      2
     4      3
    -1      4
```

dataframe B:

```
startX endX startY endY
     0    2      2    4
     3    5     -2   -1
    -2    0      0    4
```

I want get output, add column `isIn` to A:

```
valueX valueY isIn
     1      2 True
     4      3 False 
    -1      4 True
```

with condition startX <= valueX <= endX, and startY <= valueY <= endY (any row in B).

I try this:

```
dataframeA.join(dataframeB).withColumn("isIn",sf.when((dataframeA["valueX"] > dataframeB["startX"]) & (dataframeA["valueX"] < dataframeB["endX"]) & (dataframeA["valueY"] > dataframeB["startY"]) & (dataframeA["valueY"] < dataframeB["endY"]),
                        True).otherwise(False)))
```

but I have to dropDuplicates `isIn` and `valueX`, `valueY` rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can do semi and anti joins and union the results:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dfa_joined = dfa.alias('a').join(
    dfb.alias('b'), 
    F.col('a.valueX').between(F.col('b.startX'), F.col('b.endX')) & 
    F.col('a.valueY').between(F.col('b.startY'), F.col('b.endY')), 
    'left_semi'
).withColumn('isIn', F.lit(True))

dfb_joined = dfa.alias('a').join(
    dfb.alias('b'), 
    F.col('a.valueX').between(F.col('b.startX'), F.col('b.endX')) & 
    F.col('a.valueY').between(F.col('b.startY'), F.col('b.endY')), 
    'left_anti'
).withColumn('isIn', F.lit(False))

result = dfa_joined.unionAll(dfb_joined).show()
+------+------+-----+
|valueX|valueY| isIn|
+------+------+-----+
|     1|     2| true|
|    -1|     4| true|
|     4|     3|false|
+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have some other questions, if the `dfb` table is large, is it a waste of time to repeat join and judgment?

Comment: in that case you can do a normal left join and use whether the column from dfb is null as the criteria for `isIn`